# VBA code to Find a word in Column A then select values in both Columns A and Column B

Tags: vba

It's been a while since i've used VBA.

I am looking to find the word 'Q4', from here select the cell in column B. Select both columns down, until the until the word Notes: (do not include Notes:) this is my stopping point.

Hope this makes sense?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and edit as per your requirement.

```
Sub UpdateData()
Dim LastRow, i As Long
Dim startPoint, stopPoint As Integer
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Range("A" & i).value = "Q4" Then
        startPoint = i
    End If
If Range("A" & i).value = "Notes:" Then
        stopPoint = i
    End If
Next i
Range("A" & startPoint & ":B" & stopPoint).Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up writing this code instead.

```
Start = Columns(1).Find(What:="Q$", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
Stop = Columns(1).Find(What:="Notes:", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row - 2
Range("A" & Start & ":B" & Stop).Select
```